# What corner case am I missing in my algorithm that determines whether 0 or 1 character removals can make the character counts equal?

Tags: c#, string, algorithm, time-complexity

For example, it is not possible to remove 0 or 1 characters from `"aaabbbcc"` to make an equal number of each character, but it is for `"aaabbcc"` (remove 1 `'a'`).

My algorithm is passing 12/15 test cases and the ones it isn't passing have too large of input to possible debug. My guess is that there's some corner case I'm missing in my algorithm. Let me know if you see any flaws in the logic which I've detailed in comments.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
class Solution
{
    static void Main(String[] args)
    {

        string s = Console.ReadLine(); 
        // s = source string, consists of characters in range 'a', ..., 'z'

        int[] f = Enumerable.Repeat(0, 26).ToArray();
        foreach(var c in s)
            f[c - 'a'] += 1;     
        // f[0] = # of 'a' characters, ..., f[25] = # of 'z' characters

        var ff = new Dictionary<int,int>(); 
        foreach(var k in f.Where(x => x > 0)) // for non-zero character frequencies
        {
            // run an "add or increment" on the frequencies of character frequencies  
            if(ff.ContainsKey(k)) ff[k] += 1;
            else ff[k] = 1;

            if(ff.Keys.Count() > 2)
            {
                // if there are more than 2 distinct counts of characters, it is impossible to level 
                // the counts by removing a single character 
                Console.WriteLine("NO");
                return;
            }
        }
        // ff[k] = frequency of the count k of a character in s, excluding any non-zero counts

        var ffl = ff.ToList(); 
        if(ffl.Count == 2)
        {
            // If there are 2 distinct frequencies of characters, one of those frequencies must be  
            // represented only 1 time and its frequecy must be 1 more than other one. 

            // For example, if s="aaabbcc" then ffl = { {3,1}, {2,2} }, meaning that there is 1 example
            // of a character that appears 3 times (the 'a') and 2 examples of characters that appear 2
            // times (the 'b' and 'c'). So we can remove 1 'a' to level the character counts.

            // For another example, if s="aaabbbcc", then ffl = { {3,2}, {2,1} }, meaning that there are 2
            // examples of a character appearing 3 times (the 'a' and 'b') and 1 example of a 
            // character appearing 2 times (the 'c'). So we have no way of leveling the character counts.
            KeyValuePair<int,int> oneff, other;
            if(ffl[0].Value == 1)
            {
                oneff = ffl[0];
                other = ffl[1];
            }
            else if(ffl[1].Value == 1)
            {
                oneff = ffl[1]; 
                other = ffl[0];
            }
            else
            {
                 Console.WriteLine("NO");
                 return;               
            }

            if((oneff.Key - 1) != other.Key)
            {
                 Console.WriteLine("NO");
                 return;  
            }

        }

        // if we're here, there are 1 or fewer distinct counts of characters, meaning the 
        // frequency of characters in the string is already level 
        Console.WriteLine("YES");
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I found the corner case on my own. If the frequency that is represented 1 time is 1, then we're good. For example, with

```
a -> 111
b -> 111
c -> 111
d -> 111
e -> 111
f -> 111
g -> 111
h -> 111
i -> 111
j -> 0
k -> 0
l -> 0
m -> 0
n -> 1
o -> 0
p -> 0
q -> 0
r -> 0
s -> 0
t -> 0
u -> 0
v -> 0
w -> 0
x -> 0
y -> 0
z -> 0
```

we can remove the `n` character. I changed

if((oneff.Key - 1) != other.Key)

to

if((oneff.Key != 1) && (oneff.Key - 1) != other.Key)

and it worked.

Comment: What is the maximum string size??

Comment: @JishnuBanerjee How would that be relevant? (The answer to your question is 10^5, by the way).

Comment: That relates to the complexity :) Anyway, i think i can suggest another approach for you!

Comment: Oh! I see you've fixed it!

Comment: @user6048670 Can you try this simple approach: http://ideone.com/ZLESOW

Comment: Just a note: wouldn't `int[] f = new int[26];` be a lot clearer than playing with Enumerable?

Comment: @user6048670 Can you please post your fix as an answer and accept.